# build select list based on current date php

Tags: php, javascript, html

Ive created a drop select list that generates a list of dates based on the current date,

4 days back and 7 days forward, Ive tried several shorter scripts but they all fail, ive been using the following but it has some limitiations... Thanks!

```
<option value=""> select </option>
<option value="<?php echo date ("m/d/Y", mktime (0,0,0,date("m"),(date("d")-4),date("Y")));?>" style="color:red;"><?php echo date ("m/d/Y", mktime (0,0,0,date("m"),(date("d")-4),date("Y")));?></option>
<option value="<?php echo date ("m/d/Y", mktime (0,0,0,date("m"),(date("d")-3),date("Y")));?>" style="color:red;"><?php echo date ("m/d/Y", mktime (0,0,0,date("m"),(date("d")-3),date("Y")));?></option>
<option value="<?php echo date ("m/d/Y", mktime (0,0,0,date("m"),(date("d")-2),date("Y")));?>" style="color:red;"><?php echo date ("m/d/Y", mktime (0,0,0,date("m"),(date("d")-2),date("Y")));?></option>
<option value="<?php echo date ("m/d/Y", mktime (0,0,0,date("m"),(date("d")-1),date("Y")));?>" style="color:red;"><?php echo date ("m/d/Y", mktime (0,0,0,date("m"),(date("d")-1),date("Y")));?></option>
<option value="<?php echo date ('m/d/Y');?>"><?php echo date ('m/d/Y');?> TODAY </option>
<option value="<?php echo date ("m/d/Y", mktime (0,0,0,date("m"),(date("d")+1),date("Y")));?>" style="color:green;font-weight:bold;"><?php echo date ("m/d/Y", mktime (0,0,0,date("m"),(date("d")+1),date("Y")));?></option>
<option value="<?php echo date ("m/d/Y", mktime (0,0,0,date("m"),(date("d")+2),date("Y")));?>" style="color:green;font-weight:bold;"><?php echo date ("m/d/Y", mktime (0,0,0,date("m"),(date("d")+2),date("Y")));?></option>
<option value="<?php echo date ("m/d/Y", mktime (0,0,0,date("m"),(date("d")+3),date("Y")));?>" style="color:green;font-weight:bold;"><?php echo date ("m/d/Y", mktime (0,0,0,date("m"),(date("d")+3),date("Y")));?></option>
<option value="<?php echo date ("m/d/Y", mktime (0,0,0,date("m"),(date("d")+4),date("Y")));?>" style="color:green;font-weight:bold;"><?php echo date ("m/d/Y", mktime (0,0,0,date("m"),(date("d")+4),date("Y")));?></option>
<option value="<?php echo date ("m/d/Y", mktime (0,0,0,date("m"),(date("d")+5),date("Y")));?>" style="color:green;font-weight:bold;"><?php echo date ("m/d/Y", mktime (0,0,0,date("m"),(date("d")+5),date("Y")));?></option>
<option value="<?php echo date ("m/d/Y", mktime (0,0,0,date("m"),(date("d")+6),date("Y")));?>" style="color:green;font-weight:bold;"><?php echo date ("m/d/Y", mktime (0,0,0,date("m"),(date("d")+6),date("Y")));?></option>
<option value="<?php echo date ("m/d/Y", mktime (0,0,0,date("m"),(date("d")+7),date("Y")));?>" style="color:green;font-weight:bold;"><?php echo date ("m/d/Y", mktime (0,0,0,date("m"),(date("d")+7),date("Y")));?></option>
```

Comment: Could you narrow your code sample down to the relevant part (maybe use an ellipsis to denote repetition)? Also, what limitations does this have?

Comment: What are the limitations you're finding? You haven't really asked a question here...

Comment: please forgive my brevity, It's rather cumbersome, and I am attempting to compair it to a value in the database, in addition the form I have to place it into is very small and it's just a lot of repetitive code to type in if I mess up, and I've been attempting to try some examples Ive found around but keep getting something wrong

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you're asking. I've rewritten your code to make it as simple and readable as possible.

```
<?php
echo '<select>';
echo '<option value="">select</option>';

for($i = -4; $i <= 7; ++$i)
{
    $date = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($i.' days'));
    echo '<option value="'.$date.'" style="color:red;">'.$date.'</option>';
}

echo '</select>';
?>
```

Comment: If my answer has helped you out, please consider accepting it as the "best answer" for your question.

Answer (score 0):

This should suffice:

```
echo '<select><option> select </option>';

for($x=-4;$x<=7;$x++){
    $date = date("m/d/Y",(time() + (86400 * $x)));
    if($x<0){
        $color='red';
    }elseif($x==0){
        $color = 'black;font-weight:bold';
    }else{
        $color = 'green';
    }
    echo '<option style="color:'.$color.'" value="'.$date.'">'.($x==0 ? 'TODAY':$date).'</option>';
}

echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should be doing is to create a function for your calculation, 
so that you can use `mydate(+1)` , `mydate(-2)` in your code instead of that spaggheti.

Don't mix (**and repeat**) so much php code in your html, it is very bad practice and hard to maintain.

**Second**, inside your function you could turn your time to **unix timestamp** with appropriate function, add the number of miliseconds and turn it back to whatever time format you need.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
<?php
    for($i = -4; $i <= 7; $i++) {
        $date = date ("m/d/Y", mktime (0,0,0,date("m"),(date("d")-$i),date("Y")));

        $date_txt = $date;

        if($i == 0) {
            $date_txt = "Today";
        }

        printf("<option value=\"%s\" style=\"color: red\">%s</option>", $date, $date_txt);
    }
?>
```